# Record time elapsed since page refresh

Tags: jquery

Is there a way I could record and ouput in console the time elapsed since I hit refresh to a particular jquery action ?

I have this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content').load('url.jsp', function(){
        //some code or plugin that changes the layout of loaded content

        $('.content').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

I want the time taken since refresh till the `fadeIn` happens.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Date` object or `console.time` if supported in your browser.

```
console.time('foo');
var d = new Date();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content').load('url.jsp', function(){

        console.timeEnd('foo');
        console.log(new Date.getTime() - d.getTime() + 'ms');

        $('.content').fadeIn();
    });
});
```